# Javascript Logical Nullish Assignment equivalence

Tags: javascript

I was visiting [MDN article for Logical Nullish Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). The equivalence version provided by MDN was `x ?? (x = y)` which isn't clear enough and needs digging deeper.

Is this code:

```js
let x = null;

x ??= 12;
```

equivalent to:

```
let x = null;

if (x === null || x === undefined) {
  x = 12;
}
```

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment. Basically if `x` is nullish, then assignment of `12` to `x` is done.

Comment: nice, I knew of the Nullish check, but didn't know there was an assignment operator as well

Comment: just to clarify, if x is some expression, lets say a function call, Both of them are not same, as nullish assignment dont evaluate the left side

Comment: when in doubt, I use babeljs.io/repl .... https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBAHhC8EDsCuxgG4BQGYH4fwEYAmNIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env&prettier=true&targets=Node-8&version=7.14.7&externalPlugins=

Comment: After reading the docs, this part confused me - "Short circuit means that the expr part above is not evaluated, hence any side effects of doing so do not take effect (e.g., if expr is a function call, the calling never takes place)." - If the side effect to the right hand side (expr) does not take effect, then why does the right hand side show (x = y), surely thats the side effect thats doing the assignment of `y` to `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it only assigns if `x` is nullish.

```
x ?? (x = y)
```

or

```
if (x === null || x === undefined) {
  x = 12;
}
```

It is **NOT** equivalent to

```
x = x ?? y
```

There is a difference and you can verify this by using `const` instead of `let`. That way, reassignment will result in an error. This also applies to other logical assignment like AND (`&&=`) and OR (`||=`) assignment operators.

```js
// no const reassignment error here  
// because a || (a = 'updated') doesn't evaluate the second expression
// if it was a = a || 'updated', it would throw an error
const a = 'initial'
a ||= 'updated' 
console.log(a)

const b = null
b &&= 'updated'
console.log(b)

const c = 'initial'
c ??= 'updated' // c ?? (c 
console.log(c)

// The below 3 examples will evaluate the second expression 
// and const reassignment error is thrown
try {
  const d = null
  d ||= 'updated'
} catch (e) {
  console.log("|| Error: " + e.message)
}

try {
  const e = 'initial'
  e &&= 'updated'
} catch (e) {
  console.log("&& Error: " + e.message)
}

try {
  const f = null
  f ??= 'updated'
} catch (e) {
  console.log("?? Error: " + e.message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The logical nullish assignment (x ??= y) operator only assigns if x is nullish (null or undefined)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Comment: Thanks. I've visited that page. But there was no clear explanation. The MDN only said this is equivalent to `x ?? (x = y)` which is confusing and needs more exploration.